# trying to access nested dictionary keys in python

Tags: python, json

I need to load a json and read the content to edit it later. I am getting

`{TypeError}string indices must be integers`

here is the json structure (note-below is the format when json file is already loaded, else it shows double quotes)

```
data ={'a':'hello','b':'{"date1":"9/21/2021","date2":"9/22/2021"}','c':'new'}
```

when trying to access `data['b']['date1']`
it throws error

code is as follows

```
jsonfile=open(file.json, "r")
data = json.load(jsonfile)
jsonfile.close()
date = data['b']['date1']
```

Comment: this is not a nested dictionary.

Comment: Because `'b'`’s key is a *string*, not a dict.  You can use the `ast.literal_eval` function or `json` library to convert the string into a dict.

Comment: What is unclear about the message?

Comment: I want to read date1 and date2 and need to update those in the json file but while trying to access date1, I get the mentioned error. How can I access those keys that are inside b ?

Comment: can anyone tell if its not a nested dictionary then what kind of structure it is ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content of `data['b']` is a string which contains a JSON document:

```
'{"date1":"9/21/2021","date2":"9/22/2021"}'
```

Thus you should convert it first to JSON (dict / list):

```
data_b = json.loads(data['b'])
```

Now that it is converted to a dict, you can already access its keys:

```
data_b["date1"]
```

If you want to update those values, then update the dict and then convert it back to string and reassign to the original data:

```
import json

data = {'a':'hello','b':'{"date1":"9/21/2021","date2":"9/22/2021"}','c':'new'}

data_b = json.loads(data['b'])
data_b["date1"] = "updated 1"
data_b["date2"] = "updated 2"

data['b'] = json.dumps(data_b)
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
{'a': 'hello', 'b': '{"date1": "updated 1", "date2": "updated 2"}', 'c': 'new'}
```

To write it back, you have to open the file in [write-mode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) `w` and then use either [json.dump()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump) or [file.write()](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object).

```
with open("file.json", 'w') as json_file:
    # Option 1
    json.dump(data, json_file)
    # Option 2
    # json_file.write(json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: thanks for the details Niel. I still have a little confusion when writing it back to the file:

jsonfile=open(file.json, "r")
data = json.load(jsonfile)
date_1 = json.loads(data['b'])
jsonfile.close()

data_1["date1"] = "updated 1"
data_1["date2"] = "updated 2"

jsonfile = open("file.json", "w+")
jsonfile.write(json.dumps(data_1))
jsonfile.close()

how to handle that in file, its replacing the file with only b's content

Comment: @viki It is because you are only dumping `data_1` which only contains the contents for `b`. What you need is the whole `data`. I updated my answer to include how the updated json must be updated. Could you check if it works on your side?

Comment: I tried data and data_1 while dumping. The json file doesn't get any update when using data, but it gets updated and provide me only b value when using data_1. Not sure why. I have provide the code on the above comment, not sure how to format it like you are doing for proper reading

Comment: the update that we are making on data_1 is not getting into data. So the json file stays the same. not sure how to handle it

Comment: I found my mistake, I was missing one step data['b'] = json.dumps(data_b). I think I got this working with you help. Thanks a lot. Appreciate timely help

Comment: @viki Glad it helped you :) Depending on your use case, you also have the option to just store it as a dict already `{"date1":"9/21/2021"}` and not as a dict-string `'{"date1":"9/21/2021"}'` (notice the quotes). Just change the assignment to `data['b'] = data_b` and then dump to the file as usual. But take note that the next time you read the file, you don't anymore need to do `data_b = json.loads(data['b'])` because `data['b']` is not anymore a string but is already a dict. I hope I explained it well enough :)

Comment: Thanks again Neil, I got your point. I think that particular format is being used by downstream components, not sure if that change in the formatting will have any effects on the downstream jobs that are going to read those parameters. But I will try for sure. Thanks again for helping in no time.